# Enterprise Architect: Control Position or Margin of Element Title

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to configure the margin or position of an element's title in Enterprise Architect?

[image]

For example, can I move the word "Foobar" closer to the top of this packaging component to save some space?

I also noticed that some elements seem to have a minimum size even when they are empty. For example, here `Component1` cannot be smaller than whats shown in the picture, while the packaging component can made much smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot configure that for the standard EA elements.

The only way to influence something like that would be to write your own shapescript, link that to a stereotype and apply the stereotype to the element.
But that would probably be a bit too much if you only want to change the position of the name field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think that wastes a lot of space, especially when nesting components into packaging components. This makes my diagrams very large and difficult to embed them into word documents. I wonder if that is deliberate of an oversight from Sparx Systems.

Comment: Since the name of the component element seems to be somewhat higher up, I'm guessing it is an oversight. You can always report is as a bug. It is possible that Sparx will fix it if you do.

Comment: Sparx confirmed that this is a bug and will be fixed in a later version, though they did not give an ETA.

Comment: They never give ETA's on bugfixes unfortunately. It might be 6-8 weeks, but might as well be 6-8 years.

Comment: This has been open for almost 5 month now and there still does not seem to be a bug fix on the horizon. Do you have any suggestion on how I could write my own shapescript for this problem? Could I reuse the shapescript that EA is using internally for packaging components and extend that one?

Comment: No, you EA's internal shapescript are not accessible. If one of the MDG technologies has a shape that is close to the one you want to create you can use that as a basis. See https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Shapescript-Library

Comment: @lanoxx - if there is a URL for your bug report I'm happy to upvote it. This is really poor UX.

Comment: As a workaround you can delete the name of the element in its properties and then layer a text box over it with the name. Unfortunately this means that in the model explorer your element will be nameless - **totally unacceptable** to have to choose between a well-laid out document and maintaining the model.

Comment: I reported this to Sparx in Dec. 2018 but they do not have a public issue tracker and they did not give me a time estimate on when and whether it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> "As a workaround you can delete the name of the element in its properties and then layer a text box over it with the name. Unfortunately this means that in the model explorer your element will be nameless"

me too: totally unacceptable

My workaround: : You can keep the element name, but make the element text the same color as the element, and then it becomes hidden.